# QFileDialog.getOpenFileName change button text from 'Open' to 'Remove'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Remove File', "path", '*.pdf')` to select a file and get the path in order to remove it from my application. The issue is the QFileDialog.getOpenFileName window button says 'Open' when selecting a file which will be confusing to the user.

Is there any way to change the button text from 'Open' to 'Remove'/'Delete'

Answer (score 1):

When using the static method `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` the first thing is to obtain the `QFileDialog` object and for that we use a `QTimer` and the `findChild()` method:

```py
    # ...
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.on_timeout)
    filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(...,
        options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)

def on_timeout(self):
    dialog = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QFileDialog)
    # ...
```

Then you can get the text iterating over the buttons until you get the button with the searched text and change it:

```py
for btn in dialog.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    if btn.text() == "&Open":
        btn.setText("Remove")
```

That will work at the beginning but every time you interact with the `QTreeView` they show, update the text to the default value, so the same logic will have to be applied using the `currentChanged` signal from the `selectionModel()` of the `QTreeView` but for synchronization reasons it is necessary Update the text later using another `QTimer.singleShot()`, the following code is a workable example:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.on_timeout)
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "Remove File",
            "path",
            "*.pdf",
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog,
        )

    def on_timeout(self):
        dialog = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QFileDialog)
        dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QTreeView).selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(
            lambda: self.change_button_name(dialog)
        )
        self.change_button_name(dialog)

    def change_button_name(self, dialog):
        for btn in dialog.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
            if btn.text() == self.tr("&Open"):
                QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda btn=btn: btn.setText("Remove"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The first step can be avoided if the static method is not used and create the dialog using an instance of `QFileDialog`:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(
            self,
            "Remove File",
            "path",
            "*.pdf",
            supportedSchemes=["file"],
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog,
        )
        self.change_button_name(dialog)
        dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QTreeView).selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(
            lambda: self.change_button_name(dialog)
        )
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            filename = dialog.selectedUrls()[0]
            print(filename)

    def change_button_name(self, dialog):
        for btn in dialog.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
            if btn.text() == self.tr("&Open"):
                QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda btn=btn: btn.setText("Remove"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for such a detailed response. I tried to get it working but I get the error:
`dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QTreeView).selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(lambda: self.change_button_name(dialog))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'selectionModel'`

Comment: @ZakKyriakou Have you used my code without modifying it?

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciate the [solution provided by @eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59657122/2001654), I'd like to propose a variation.

Under certain circumstances, the code for that answer might fail, specifically:

- the delay that X11 suffers from mapping windows;
- the checking of localized button strings;
- the selection using the file name edit box;

Considering the above, I propose an alternate solution, based on the points above.

For obvious reasons, the main point remains: the dialog **must** be non-native.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class FileDialogTest(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.fileEdit = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.fileEdit)

        self.selectBtn = QToolButton(icon=QIcon.fromTheme('folder'),  text='…')
        layout.addWidget(self.selectBtn)

        self.selectBtn.clicked.connect(self.showSelectDialog)

    def checkSelectDialog(self):
        dialog = self.findChild(QFileDialog)
        if not dialog.isVisible():
            # wait for dialog finalization, as testOption might fail
            return

        # dialog found, stop the timer and delete it
        self.sender().stop()
        self.sender().deleteLater()

        if not dialog.testOption(dialog.DontUseNativeDialog):
            # native dialog, we cannot do anything!
            return
        
        def updateOpenButton():
            selection = tree.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
            if selection and not tree.model().isDir(selection[0]):
                # it's a file, change the button text
                button.setText('Select my precious file')

        tree = dialog.findChild(QTreeView)
        button = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox).button(
            QDialogButtonBox.Open)

        # check for selected files on open
        updateOpenButton()

        # connect the selection update signal
        tree.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(
            lambda: QTimer.singleShot(0, updateOpenButton))

    def showSelectDialog(self):
        QTimer(self, interval=10, timeout=self.checkSelectDialog).start()
        path, filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 
            'Select file', '<path_to_file>', 
            "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py);; PNG Files (*.png)", 
            options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        if path:
            self.fileEdit.setText(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FileDialogTest()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Obviously, for PyQt6 you'll need to use the proper Enum namespaces (i.e. `QFileDialog.Option.DontUseNativeDialog`, etc.).